# Issue with QT and Android 8.0: Error creating SSL context ()

Tags: android, c++, qt, http, ssl

After the launch of Android 8.0, our QT App is not working properly on devices with this new version. The error we are seeing in our emulator is "Error creating SSL context ()". The app runs normally, but when it tries to make a HTTP call it fails.

We have this line in our AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
```

I have tried to change this targetSdkVersion sometimes, but nothing works.

Also, we make the HTTP call using this function

```
void UrlLoader::load()
{
    this->setProperty("loading", true);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setUrl(m_url);

    QUrlQuery postData;

    if(params() != "") {
        QStringList pieces = params().split( "&" );
        foreach(QString value, pieces) {
            QStringList values = value.split( "=" );
            postData.addQueryItem(values[0], values[1]);
        }
    }

    m_netMan->post(request, postData.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
}
```

The error is shown when we try to read the result:

```
void UrlLoader::finished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    this->setProperty("loading", false);
    QJsonArray jsonArray;
    QJsonObject json;
    int error = reply->error();

    if(error == 0){
        QByteArray rawData = reply->readAll();
        if(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData).isArray()) {
            jsonArray = QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData).array();
            emit this->loadedArray(jsonArray);
        } else {
            json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData).object();
            if(json.empty()){
                this->setResponse(rawData);
            }
            emit this->loaded(json);
        }
        reply->abort ();
    } else {
        emit this -> crashed(this -> retornaError(error)) ;
    }
}
```

Can someone help us?
Best Regards.

Comment: just to add, everything works fine for android 7 (android sdk 25), the problem occurs only in android 8 (android sdk 26)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your use of private SSL native libraries are no longer compatible with the Android target API level.   Check out the [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html), as well as the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html) , section NDK Apps Linking to Platform Libraries.

Comment: I read in the Qt doc that "You can use the QSslSocket::supportsSsl() static function to check for SSL support on the target." I've tried it and it return true, wouldn't that be an indication that it should work?